# why CSS direct child selector applies style to indirect children

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code:

```
<div id="test">
<span>
    test 
    <span>test</span>
</span>        
</div>
```

And the following CSS code:

```
#test > span {
color: red;
}
```

Isn't the above code supposed to select only the direct child span of test div? So only the first 'test' word should be red but the second 'test' word inside the child span should not be selected. Or I'm getting it all wrong??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All else being equal, the default style for the span will be:

```
span { color: inherit; }
```

So, while the rule `color: red;` won't apply to it directly, it will take its color from the parent element's color.

For comparison, see [what happens if you explicitly say `span { color: blue; }`](http://jsbin.com/owucih/1/edit).

Comment: You could do something like: `span{
    color: black;
}
#test > span {
color: red;
}`

Comment: So what's the use of this selector if it will anyway apply the styling to all children and children of children unless their own styling is defined???

Comment: Not all properties are inherited.  Generally speaking, if it alters the text at all (color, font-family, etc.), it probably inherits.  Otherwise, it probably doesn't.

Comment: @MichaelSamuel — Because (a) As cimmanon says, not all properties are inherited and (b) You can specify a less specific general value for properties which are.

Comment: i assume it applies to properties that have their default value as 'inherit'...right??

Answer (score -2):

Simply keep you style for the first span child element.

```
    #test > span {
    color: red; 
    }
```

And add a style for the second span child element.

```
    <div id="test">
    <span>test 
    <span style="color: black;">test</span>
    </span>        
    </div>
```

Or you can set a class for the span element like this.

```
    .red_color {
    color: red; 
    }
```

And add it to your span element.

```
    <div id="test">
    <span>test 
    <span class="red_color">test</span>
    </span>        
    </div>
```