# Confused about the nature of Parent-child relationship in HTML

Tags: html, css

```html
<header class="header header-home main-grid">
  <div class="header-content">
    <a class="logo-link" href="index.html">
      <img src="logo.svg" alt="" class="logo">
    </a>
    <button aria-label="Open navigation" class="open-nav">&#9776;</button>
    <nav class="nav">
      <button aria-label="Close navigation" class="close-nav">&times;</button>
      <ul class="nav-list">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="index.html" class="nav-link current">home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="about.html" class="nav-link">about us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="contact.html" class="nav-link">contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

in this HTML - the main grid is on the header - than he creates another div header-content to hold the logo and navbar.

What I dont understand is how the children of header-content are still affected by the header parents main-grid.

Basically the way I'm reading this is that the div is a child to the header, and i thought that flexbox/grid only affected its direct children.

If the main-grid class is on the header - why is it still affecting the content of the div even though the content isnt a direct child to the main-grid?

Comment: There is what we call inheritance mechanism in html where certain properties are passed down from parent to its child elements lest you specify the value for properties. You can further read here: [Inheritance and cascade](https://webplatform.github.io/docs/tutorials/inheritance_and_cascade/) and 
here (why CSS direct child selector applies style to indirect children)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023215/why-css-direct-child-selector-applies-style-to-indirect-children]. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Each parent will affect all of his children and all of his children's children, etc. In another word, if you know about **inheritance**, all of the nodes in HTML are inheriting the features of their parents by default.

You can overwrite a style or behavior of a child by specifying that in its own definition. For example, if the background of a parent is black, all of its children will have a black background unless you mention `background-color:'white'` in the definition of a child node.

Comment: Okay but if that is true why do I have to always write in my styles 

.nav ul {
display: flex
}

if i only target my .nav and do display it does nothing to the unordered list, why is that?

Comment: Can you show me what you mean? A minimal producible code.

Comment: .nav-flexbox ul {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1rem;

}
//////////
i cant just say .nav-flexbox - it wont work then, i have to say ".nav-flexbox ul" and if what you said is true idk why i have to use a compound selector to make it work